# Create user-defined correlation matrix in R

Tags: r, function, matrix, correlation

Say that I have a correlation coefficient, C, which is user-defined, so that I have created the function C(x,y) to compute this correlation between two variables. This function gives three outputs (it's a vector) A, B, and C, where C is the correlation. Say that I have a dataset with many variables (x,y,z,w, etc.) and that I want to get the correlation matrix with all the pairwise C coefficients. How can implement that in R? I would like the output to be like the one given by the cor() function already available in R. I have tried a lot of things (loops, combn, apply, but nothing seems to work fine).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have a user-defined function that calculates the correlation between two vectors as a single scalar, perhaps something like this:

```r
C <- function(x, y) {
  n <- length(x)
  (n * sum(x * y) - sum(x) * sum(y)) /
    sqrt(abs(n * sum(x^2) - sum(x)^2) * abs(n * sum(y^2) - sum(y)^2))
}
```

In fact, if we test this on two random vectors we will see we get the same output as we do from `cor`:

```r
set.seed(1)
x <- 1:5/10 + rnorm(5)
y <- 2:6/10 + rnorm(5)

C(x, y)
#> [1] 0.410903
cor(x, y)
#> [1] 0.410903
```

However, an important difference is that we can give `cor` a data frame and it will calculate all pairwise correlations between the columns, outputting a matrix, as we can see if we pass it the first 4 columns of the built-in `iris` data set:

```r
cor(iris[1:4])
#>              Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> Sepal.Length    1.0000000  -0.1175698    0.8717538   0.8179411
#> Sepal.Width    -0.1175698   1.0000000   -0.4284401  -0.3661259
#> Petal.Length    0.8717538  -0.4284401    1.0000000   0.9628654
#> Petal.Width     0.8179411  -0.3661259    0.9628654   1.0000000
```

But clearly this won't work with our hand-rolled function `C`:

```r
C(iris[1:4])
#> Error in C(iris[1:4]): argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

The most straightforward way to achieve the same kind of output with our own hand-rolled function is to build a matrix, and iterate over both dimensions of it, populating each entry *[i, j]* with the correlation of the *i<sup>th</sup>* and *j<sup>th</sup>* column of the data frame using a double loop:

```r
C_dataframe <- function(x) {
  m <- matrix(0, ncol = ncol(x), nrow = ncol(x), 
              dimnames = list(names(x), names(x)))
  for(i in seq(nrow(m))) {
    for(j in seq(ncol(m))) {
      m[i, j] <- C(x[[i]], x[[j]])
    }
  }
  m
}
```

Now testing this, using only our own user-defined function, we get exactly the same output from `C_dataframe` as we would get from `cor`:

```r
C_dataframe(iris[1:4])
#>              Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> Sepal.Length    1.0000000  -0.1175698    0.8717538   0.8179411
#> Sepal.Width    -0.1175698   1.0000000   -0.4284401  -0.3661259
#> Petal.Length    0.8717538  -0.4284401    1.0000000   0.9628654
#> Petal.Width     0.8179411  -0.3661259    0.9628654   1.0000000
```